# On decreasing the $L^2$ distance between parametric probability densities by adjusting the parameter.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $p(x| \theta)$ be a parametric probability density function with $\theta$ taking values in $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $\theta_1, \theta_2$ be such that $| \theta_1 - \theta | > |\theta_2 - \theta|$ then is it true that the $L^2$ distance between $p(x| \theta)$ and $p(x| \theta_1)$ will be greater than the one between $p(x| \theta)$ and $p(x| \theta_2)$, i. e., does

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} (p(x| \theta) - p(x| \theta_1))^2 \ dx > \int_{\mathbb{R}} (p(x| \theta) - p(x| \theta_2))^2 \ dx $$

hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. There is no connection of the distances between parameters and pdfs. You can say that $\theta\in\Theta=\{1,2,100\}$ with 
$$p(x\mid 1)=e^{-x}I(x>0), \quad p(x\mid 2)=500e^{-500x}I(x>0), \quad p(x\mid 100)=2e^{-2x}I(x>0)$$
For this case $L_2$ distance between $p(x\mid 1)$ and $p(x\mid 2)$ equals to $\frac{250001}{1002}$ and $L_2$ distance between $p(x\mid 1)$ and $p(x\mid 100)$ equals to $\frac56$.  And $|1-2|\ll |1-100|$.

Comment: Thanks for this, could there be some condition under which it becomes true?

Comment: Only some strange conditions will help. For example, if $p(x\mid\theta)$ is non-decreasing in $\theta$ for each $x$, then $|p(x\mid\theta_1)-p(x\mid\theta)|>|p(x\mid\theta_2)-p(x\mid\theta)|$ and the desired inequality follows.